# Linear interpolation optimization

Tags: interpolation

I want to interpolate any function $f(x)$ using only linear interpolation. So far I have found that the following equations do the trick pretty well. 
$$m(a,b,x)=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+f(a)$$
$$L(a,b,x)=(a-x)(x-b)$$
$$T(x)=\frac 12(1+\mathrm {sign} (x))$$
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(v+(n-1)h,v+nh,x)T(L(v+(n-1)h,v+nh,x))$$
Where $h$ is the size of the intervals on which the function is interpolated, it can easily be stated that $F(x) \to f(x)$ as $h \to 0$. The error between both interpolations can be found with:
$$R=f(x)-F(x)$$
However, I was thinking that maybe there is a function of $R$ that could maximize $h$ within an interval $[a,b]$, i.e. given the error $R$, what is the biggest $h$ that could yield that $R$ within an interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: To even approach this, you would need to have some conditions on $f$.

Comment: which ones? maybe i can edit the question

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you have some application in mind?

Comment: working with lines is so much easier than working with curves, especially when dealing with diophantine equations. Mostly, I want to approximate any function $f(x)$ to count the number of solutions to diophantine equations of the sort $\sum_{n=1}^m \lfloor f(x_n) \rceil=N$. This optimization will ease the computations for the purpose of graphing the solutions.

Comment: Surely the graphing software can deal with polynomials directly?

Comment: sure it can, but I can't, and I would like to work with lines rather than curves

Comment: Are you trying to solve the following semi infinite program? $\max\{ h | |f(a+th)-(f(a)+t(f(b)-f(a))| \le R, \ \forall t \in [0,1] \}$?

Comment: I don't know what semi infinite programs are

Comment: The $t $ takes values in $[0,1]$ rather than a finite set. If you just need an approximation, a LP will suffice for $t ={ k\over n}$, $ k=0,...n$ or similar.

Comment: And how do I solve these programs? Will the solution give me the optimization of $h$ as a function of $R$?